# Mark repeated tasks done for good!

Tags: org-mode

Short of editing the task and removing the repeater token, is there absolutely any way to mark a repeated task done so that it does not repeat any more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to orgmode manual ([8.3.2 Repeated tasks](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Repeated-tasks)):

> To mark a task with a repeater as DONE, use `C-- 1 C-c C-t` (i.e., `org-todo` with a numeric prefix argument of `-1`.)

You could use `C-u - 1` instead of `C-- 1`.

It calls `(org-cancel-repeater)` function

```
(defun org-cancel-repeater ()
  "Cancel a repeater by setting its numeric value to zero."
  ...
```

In `org-agenda` this could be done with the same prefix `C-- 1 t`.  This calls function `org-agenda-todo`

```
(defun org-agenda-todo (&optional arg)
  "Cycle TODO state of line at point, also in Org-mode file.
  This changes the line at point, all other lines in the agenda referring to
  the same tree node, and the headline of the tree node in the Org-mode file."
```

And inside the function it calls `(org-todo)` with the same prefix argument

```
...
(let ((current-prefix-arg arg))
  (call-interactively 'org-todo))
...
```